# Create file with UTF-16LE encoding

Tags: kotlin, io

I am trying to create a tab separate CSV via kotlin.
For the requirement we need to have UTF-16LE for the produced file encoding.

My stripped down code is something like this:

```
import java.io.File
import java.io.FileOutputStream
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val fileOutputStream = FileOutputStream(File("bla.csv"))
    val writer = OutputStreamWriter(fileOutputStream, Charsets.UTF_16LE)
    writer.write("bla\tbla\tbla")
    writer.write("\n")
    writer.write("lab\tlab\tlab")
    writer.flush()
    writer.close()
}
```

So after executing this program the file generated has this information:
(I am running file on the actual file)

```
file -I bla.csv 
bla.csv: application/octet-stream; charset=binary
```

This is what I get when I go for

> Charsets.UTF_16LE

I have tried using other UTF-16 variation which made me even more confuse!

So if I use Charsets.UTF_16 it will result in:

```
file -I bla.csv 
bla.csv: text/plain; charset=utf-16be
```

And if I use Charsets.UTF_16BE it will result in:

```
file -I bla.csv 
bla.csv: application/octet-stream; charset=binary
```

So after a lot of self doubt and being sure that I am doing something wrong I have give up and come here.

Any guidance will be appreciated. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect this is a limitation of the `file` command, and not a problem with your code (which is fine*).

If you write a Byte Order Mark (`\uFEFF`) as the first character of the file, then `file` recognises it fine:

```
> file bla.csv 
bla.csv: Little-endian UTF-16 Unicode text
> file -I bla.csv 
bla.csv: text/plain; charset=utf-16le
```

The file should be perfectly valid without a BOM, though.  So I'm not sure why `file` isn't recognising it.  It *may* be that it's not always possible to safely identify UTF16-LE without a BOM, though you'd think a case like this (where every other byte is 0) would be a safe bet!

---

<sup>(* Well, there are always potential improvements…  For example, it'd be safer to wrap the output in a call to `writer.use()` instead of closing the file manually.  You could wrap the `OutputStreamWriter` in a `BufferedWriter` for efficiency.  And in production code, you'd want some error handling, of course.  But none of that's related to the question!)</sup>

Comment: Thanks for the answer writing FEFF solved the issue. Just for information this problem originated that the Excel could not open the file but with these characters it works.

Comment: Regarding the catch block I think you misunderstood. This is just a sample fast code to show case the issue. Of course I will not have empty catch ;)

Comment: @Khashayar I guessed that — but I couldn't see why you'd used the `try`…`catch` at all, since it could be omitted completely :-)  (Plus, we have a heavy responsibility to future generations who might look at the question in future and think it's a good idea.)  BTW, if Excel can handle UTF-8, that might be a better bet — it's become the de-facto standard for text, so should be more widely compatible.

Comment: yes the reason we going for URF-16LE is very specific to the domain we have but otherwise I think everyone should push UTF-8 :)

Comment: And im gonna remove the try catch from the question